# Fast way to "flatten" hierarchy table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, hierarchy, bigdata

I've got a very huge table with hierarchy which can not be modified. Nodes in the table have an `Id`, `ParentId`, a `Level` and some data. The `Level` means that node with level `N` can be a child not only for level `N-1` but also for level `N-2`, `N-3` etc. The good news are that the number of levels is limited - there are only 8 of them. Level 1 is on the top of the hierarchy and level 8 is the end of it.

And now I need to flatten that table with respect to the place of the levels. The result should be like this:

```
Lvl1   Lvl2   Lvl3   ...   Lvl8
xxx    xxx    null         xxx
xxx    null   xxx          xxx
xxx    null   null         xxx
xxx    xxx    xxx          xxx
```

**First step**
As the level number is limited, the first idea was to `LEFT JOIN` several times all the table on `ParentId = Id`. But this made levels change their place, as level 6 could be skipped and level 5 took it's place.

**Second step** So I've used `CASE WHEN` to select value depending on the row's level.

```
-- LEVEL 4
CASE
    WHEN lvl6.[Level] = 4 THEN lvl6.Data -- in case levels 6 and 5 were skipped, we can find 4th level data here
    WHEN lvl5.[Level] = 4 THEN lvl5.Data
    WHEN lvl4.[Level] = 4 THEN lvl4.Data
    ELSE NULL
END AS l4Data,
```

It solved my problem but it was VERY slow.

**Third step** The combination of levels is also limited (`1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8`, `1-3-5-6-7-8`, etc.) So I decided to use more `LEFT JOIN`s to glue all combinations of levels together:

```
WITH
   l7 AS (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE [Level] = 7),
   l6 AS (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE [Level] = 6),
...
FROM l7
...
LEFT JOIN l6 AS l6_7 ON l7.ParentId = l6_7.Id       -- 7-6-5-4-1
LEFT JOIN l5 AS l5_7 ON l6_7.ParentId = l5_7.Id
LEFT JOIN l4 AS l4_7 ON l5_7.ParentId = l4_7.Id
LEFT JOIN l1 AS l1_7 ON l4_7.ParentId = l1_7.Id
```

And then I selected data using `COALESCE`:

```
COALESCE(l3.Data, l3_1.Data, l3_2.Data, l3_3.Data) AS l3Data,
```

It made my query VERY complicated and hard to extend, but as for now it's the fastest result I've achieved.

Are there any faster and tiny ways to flattern that table? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typical use is a CTE, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Thanks, comment back if the answer below isn't clear, I'll post something

Comment: I'd appreciate your help, as I can't see how the Shnugo's answer can process the situation where one or multiple levels are skipped

Comment: Generally speaking you can have neat code or fast code but often not both

Comment: Possibly what you need to clarify in your question (please provide an example) is that a given node A on level 7 can have a direct parent node B on level 2 and there are no intermediate levels defined. If you provide this as example data it may be clearer to everyone (as well as confirm this assumption)

Answer (score 5):

This is an example how you could go with a recursive CTE:

To be honest: I'd not expect this to be very fast with **huge** data...

There is the [`HIERARCHYID` data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213(v=sql.110).aspx), but you said, that you are not allowed to change the table's structure...

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100),id INT,parentId INT);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('Element 1',1,0)
,('Element 1.1',2,1)
,('Element 1.2',3,1)
,('Element 1.3',4,1)

,('Element 1.1.1',5,2)
,('Element 1.1.2',6,2)
,('Element 1.2.1',7,3)

,('Element 1.2.1.1',8,7)
,('Element 1.2.1.2',9,7);


WITH CTE AS
( 
       SELECT   * 
              ,CAST(parentId AS VARCHAR(MAX))  + ',' + CAST(CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS IdListTopDown
                ,CAST(Name AS varchar(MAX)) AS NameList
    FROM @t
    WHERE parentId = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.* 
             ,CAST(c.IdListTopDown AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',' + CAST(CAST(t.id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
               ,CAST(c.NameList + ' | ' + t.Name AS varchar(MAX))
       FROM @t AS t
       JOIN CTE c ON c.id = t.parentId
)
SELECT  CTE.*
FROM  CTE
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @t WHERE parentId=CTE.id)
ORDER BY CTE.IdListTopDown
```

The result

```
Element 1.1.1       5   2   0,1,2,5     Element 1 | Element 1.1 | Element 1.1.1
Element 1.1.2       6   2   0,1,2,6     Element 1 | Element 1.1 | Element 1.1.2
Element 1.2.1.1     8   7   0,1,3,7,8   Element 1 | Element 1.2 | Element 1.2.1 | Element 1.2.1.1
Element 1.2.1.2     9   7   0,1,3,7,9   Element 1 | Element 1.2 | Element 1.2.1 | Element 1.2.1.2
Element 1.3         4   1   0,1,4       Element 1 | Element 1.3
```

Comment: I've used your code as a starting point. And it takes minutes to execute on my table (about 1.2KK records)

Comment: @Waldemar, I'm afraid, there is no really fast way... Especially with such extra rules like gaps. In a similar case I have a query with a bunch of `CROSS APPLYs`. i start with the outer most elements (those, whose ID is not used as parentID) and work the hierarchy upwards. The advantage: You can be sure, that there is a parent (therefore `CROSS` ) But this isn't very fast too. In my case I use a nightly job to write a flat table out...

Comment: thanks for your help any way. right now the solution, I've described in step 3, takes 3-5 seconds to search over the view and I start thinking of storing that view in a table to increase search speed.

Comment: In re: hierarchy. While the OP may not be able to change the table's structure, s/he could create a new table that references this one that has just the ID and a calculated hierarchyid. Assuming that it's kept up to date on DML operations, you get the speed of hierarchyid without having to modify the base table.

Comment: @BenThul OK, but in this case I'd prefer a triggered side table with flattened data (at least the IDs side by side...)